# how to use xml file in ajax chat?

Tags: ajax, xml

I want to build a website like Facebook style, and for start i am building a chat system using ajax. For now, all the messages that are sent to the chat system are saved in a xml file which looks like this:

```
<messages>
<message from="jhon" time="2:00">Hi!</message>
</messages>
```

My question is if it is fine to use the xml file like i do here, or a database is the solution. Can someone explain to me how to use xml in the right way also in the chat or a messages system if it is necessary at all?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I made an exercise (for school) that worked in a simular way:

```
<post>
    <time>15:25</time>
    <name>myUserName</name>
    <message>testbla</message>
</post>
```

I used a PHP-script (provided by the teacher) to write in the file (in the format like before) each time there is a new message being sent by the user. While it was working well, there were a few problems I encountered:

- In order to keep the chat updated, I had to reload the chat 3600 times per hour. This is no problem. However, because I was using XML, I had to download the file 3600x per hour, which is definitely not an elegant solution; with only a few messages, the site consumed about 20-40 MB data each hour. (you do the math!)
- There were also issues with the special chars that conflicted to XML: `<`, `>` and `&`. I had to either escape them, remove them from the user input *OR* use CDATA to prevent XML from crashing due to syntax errors. (XML is very sensitive for this!) Additional difficulty was to prevent that others could send bad code. Generally, try to eliminate this while updating your XML-file.

With the above in mind, I would recommend searching for a more elegant solution than XML; JSON might be lighter to handle. Alternatively, MYSQL/PHP allow you to send only the last messages, so you don't have to send the whole file over and over again. (I don't have any PHP/MYSQL-expertise at this moment, so I cannot help you with that right now)

You asked how you could make your XML-chat happen. To give you some direction, I will give you some snippets of my code (with jQuery):

```
/* this function gets chat logs from XML and manipulate the content to a
   div used for the chat-content. It is being evaluated each second by 
   an interval that calls the function each 1000 ms. (not included in this code) */

function getChatLogs() {

    var chatLogs = "";
    $.ajax({
        url: "chat_log.xml",
        success: function(data) {

        $(data).find("post").each(function() {
            var timeMessage = $(this).find("time").text();
            var nameSender = $(this).find("name").text();
            var contentMessage = $(this).find("message").text();

            chatLogs += "<article><time>" + timeMessage + "</time> <strong>" + nameSender + "</strong> <p>" + contentMessage+ "</p></article>";
        });
            $("#chat").html(chatLogs);

            }
        });
}

/* this function handles messages being send by the user */

function sendInput(keyCode) {

    if(keyCode === 13 && $("#post").val() != "") {
        var name = localStorage.getItem("username"); // I used localstorage fo username
        var time = currentTime();
        var message = $("#post").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "save.php",
            data: {"name": name, "time": time, "message": message},
            success: function(data) {
                $("#post").val(""); // (clear the chat-input)
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Bonus tip: you XML-file MUST be well formed. You can easily check if this is the case by opening the XML-file straight in Chrome. If there are issues, it will give an error.

Comment: But if i want to save all the messages, so i will be able to show all the conversation next time the user will log in? Something the database can't do (as you said).

Comment: You can use XML, but keep my concerns in mind. It might not be the slimmest solution, especially if you have a lot of users.
Concerning databases: it depends on how you implement it. Facebook - your given example - will only load the last x messages and will only allow further tracking if you scroll up. That doesn't mean they haven't got your data. If you implement your database & handler well, you can send messages the way you like: only the newest, the last x, all of them... you don't have to lose any of your data. (you could use two handlers: one on start-up and one to update your page)